# Stop loading admob ads after click

Tags: android, admob, adview

I would like to stop the loading of ads after the user clicking on adview I already implemented adlistener and I put adView.stopLoading(); on onDismissScreen , but I get the following error when I close the ad web page:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1059): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {ivn.com.teletextinternational/com.google.ads.AdActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, AdListener {
RelativeLayout relativeLayout1;
 ImageView imgpag; 
 FrameLayout frameLayout1;
 FrameLayout frameLayout2;
 Button right;
 Button left;
 ProgressBar probar;
 LinearLayout linear;
 AdView adView;
 EditText numbox;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    imgpag = (ImageView)findViewById (R.id.imgpag); 
    relativeLayout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);
    frameLayout1 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout1);
    frameLayout2 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout2);
    left = (Button) findViewById(R.id.left);
    right = (Button) findViewById(R.id.right);
    probar = (ProgressBar) findViewById (R.id.probar);
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14ebbcd3aae1ff");

    LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.linear);
    linear.addView(adView);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    adView.setAdListener(this);
 }

public void onDismissScreen(Ad arg0) {
    adView.stopLoading();
            linear.setVisibility(View.GONE);//if you want hide ads
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just this instead:

```
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14ebbcd3aae1ff");
```

You created a local adView object instead of initializing your adView field.  As a result, adView was null when you tried calling stopLoading().

Comment: does not work, I don't get back the error but nothing happens adview still loading ads.
Also if I add linear.removeView(adView); I get back the same error as before

Comment: Is your use case that you don't want the ad to refresh anymore, but you still want it to display?  I believe stopLoading just stops the ad from loading if it already began that process, but that I think stopLoading is more useful for interstitial ads.  As for the `linear` error, you are making the same mistake where you are defining a local linear object instead of initializing the linear field.